# MySQL, How to select one row from first table and two from the second one

Tags: mysql, select

I need to SELECT one row from first table and two rows from second one that correspond to the result from the first one. I can explain it more clearly using example.

As shown below I have two tables. Table "Games" have information about games between teams (e.g. game nr 1 is played by team NR 10 and team NR 11). In second table I simply have teams' names. The question is how to using one Select get information about game together with teams names from second table?

e.g. I want to get information who plays game NR 3  together with teams' names. Result should be:

```
id = 3, team_nr1 = 14, team_nr2 = 15, team1_name = eee, team2_name = fff
```

Is it even possible?

```
Table: Games
________________________
id  team_nr1    team_nr2
1   10          11
2   12          13
3   14          15

Table: Teams
________________________
team_id team_name
10      aaa
11      bbb
12      ccc
13      ddd
14      eee
15      fff
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use joins. It could look like this:

```
SELECT G.id, G.team_nr1, G.team_nr2,
       T1.team_name AS team1_name, T2.team_name AS team2_name
FROM Games G
LEFT JOIN Teams T1 ON (G.team_nr1 = T1.team_id)
LEFT JOIN Teams T2 ON (G.team_nr2 = T2.team_id)
WHERE G.id = 3
```

There are also other types of joins. `LEFT JOIN` means that all games are listed, even if there are no matching teams in `T1` or `T2`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:-

```
SELECT ID,
       TEAM_NR1,
       TEAN_NR2,
       (SELECT TEAM_NAME
            FROM TEAMS
            WHERE TEAMS.TEAM_ID = GAMES.TEAM_NR1) AS TEAM1_NAME,
       (SELECT TEAM_NAME
            FROM TEAMS
            WHERE TEAMS.TEAM_ID = GAMES.TEAM_NR2) AS TEAM2_NAME
    FROM GAMES
    WHERE GAMES.ID = 3;
```

The subqueries pick out the required team names and name the "column" in which they appear.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have only 1 row with all your values, the only way I can thing of is using the [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function. I would not recommend the use on inline queries oe subqueries because in case of no record found it will produce a mysql error.